# Running Docker Containers on Docker Swarm using Marathon?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon, docker-swarm

I successfully integrated Docker Swarm with mesos and everything is going fine.

But now I can start containers on Docker swarm only from the Command line like this:

```
docker -H :4375 run -idt --cpu-shares 1 busybox.
```

I am using Marathon for job scheduling in my cluster; is there any way to start a docker container on docker swarm integrated with mesos using Marathon?

Is it possible to do it with some other scheduler other than Marathon?

Comment: What about Kubernetes? http://kubernetes.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can launch Docker containers directly through Marathon. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163843/spark-mesos-cluster-mode-is-slower-than-local-mode) is the API reference that explains how to do so from the command line, but you can also launch your containers using [Marathon web interface](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/application-basics.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply.. Ya it is possible to run docker containers using Marathon on mesos.. But I need to start container on Docker Swarm integrated with Mesos using Marathon...